# Javascript - Pass html string containing variables as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, parameters

I want to execute a function that appends (jQuery) a li to an ul. Now I want to pass a string as a parameter that looks like:

```
v.name + " by " + v.artist
```

The problem is that the v.name and v.artist don't exist outside the function, because the function contains an .each loop:

```
function showAllItems (data, displayText) {
    $("ul.result-list").empty();
    $.each(data.results, function (k, v) {
        var name = eval(displayText);
        if ($("ul.chosen-list input#" + v.name).length == 0) {
            $("ul.result-list")
                .append($("<li>")
                    .append($("<input>", {id: v.name, value: v.name, type: "checkbox"}))
                    .append($("<label>", {html: name, for: v.name, class: "clickable"})));
        }
    });
}
```

What I am using now is eval(displayText) to convert a string into a real variable. But now I can't pass something like I said earlier (v.name + " by " + v.artist).

In short, I want to print a string containing variables that don't exist until the .each loop.

I hope someone can help me!

Thanks in advance,

Ian Wensink

Comment: Why wouldn't it exist, and what do you mean when you claim you're converting a string into a "real variable" ?

Comment: Well, I want to print v.name, but v doesn't exist outside the each loop, because that's the value. So I want to pass into the function that it needs to print v.name, but v.name doesn't have a value yet. That's why it has to be a string, which needs to be converted into a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback function to create the value:

```
function showAllItems (data, getDisplayText) {
  $("ul.result-list").empty();
  $.each(data.results, function (k, v) {
    if ($("ul.chosen-list input#" + v.name).length == 0) {
      var name = getDisplayText(v);
      $("ul.result-list")
        .append($("<li>")
          .append($("<input>", {id: v.name, value: v.name, type: "checkbox"}))
          .append($("<label>", {html: name, for: v.name, class: "clickable"}))
        );
    }
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
showAllItems(data, function(v){ return v.name + " by " + v.artist; });
```

Comment: The `.append` functions need to be fixed too... appending the `input` and `label` to the `ul` and not the `li`

Comment: But they should be appended to the li, don't they?

Comment: @Mottie: They should be inside the list item. You can't have them in the list outside a list item.

Comment: Look at the source of [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/o4pqfx7e/) in Chrome... the `li`s, `input`s and `label`s are all *direct* children of the `ul`.

Comment: Well, besides that discussion, your callback idea worked! I am so thankful!

Comment: So @Ian, it would be better to only "touch" the DOM once... build the list item first (as a jQuery object or string), then append the whole thing to the `ul`.

Comment: Hmm, I can get into that. Will think of that from now on! Thanks, again!

Comment: @Mottie: That's different code, showing a problem that doesn't exist in the code in the answer. I fixed the demo so that it uses the same way to create and append the list item: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/o4pqfx7e/1/

Comment: Oh, you're right, I guess I missed all the extra parentheses... thats what I get for looking at code when I'm sick LOL